# JDBC connection over internet without ssl

Tags: java, security, jdbc

Is JDBC connection to a remote database over the internet without SSL but authentication with username and password enabled is insecure ? Is attack like man in the middle possible for such scenarios ?

Comment: SSL/TLS/HTTPS was not invented because evil scientists wanted to make the life of IT engineers harder you know... it was invented because it was desperately needed.

Comment: Instead of connecting to a remote database over the internet, consider if instead you should use a rest service to mediate between the database and the big bad internet.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication NOT implies confidentiality. SSL/TLS was born to grant the latter. So you have to use a secured connection. But I'd suggest you to not expose you DB to the Internet. Use a microservices-like pattern to isolate the DB from unwanted exposures.

Answer (score 0):

It is insecure, never expose your database on internet, not even using ssl. If you really need to do so, make a ssh tunnel or configure a vpn.